# CSV: alternative to excel "IF" statement in python. Read column and create a new one with numpy.where or other function

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I have a CSV file with several columns and I want to write a code that will read a specific column called *'ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount'* and then, create a new column called "Logical" which will be based on numpy.where(). Here is what I got at the moment:

```
csv_data = pd.read_csv("Results.csv")

data = csv_data[['ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount']]
data = data.to_numpy()

sol = []
for target in data:
    if1 = np.where(data < 0, 1, 0)
    sol.append(if1)

csv_data["Logical"] = [sol].values
csv_data.to_csv ('Results2.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

This loop is made incorrectly and does not work. It does not create a new column with the corresponding value for each row. To make it clear: if the value in the column is bigger than 0, it will record "1", otherwise "0". The solution can be in any way (nor np.where(), nor loop is required)

If you want to understand what is "Results.csv"
[image]

It is actually a big file with data, I have highlighted the column we work with. The code needs to check if there is a value bigger than 0 in the column and give back 1 or 0 in the new column (as I described in the question)

Comment: `csv_data['Logical'] = np.where(csv_data['ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount'] > 0, 1, 0)` or just do `csv_data['Logical'] = (csv_data['ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount'] > 0).astype(int)`

Comment: @It_is_Chris can I ask to show how to implement it to the code because I have tried this version but still does not work? Maybe I do some pre/post work incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## updated answer

```
import pandas as pd 

f1 = pd.read_csv("L1.csv") 
f2 = pd.read_csv("L2.csv") 

f3 = pd.merge(f1, f2, on ='CTN', how ='inner') 

# f3.to_csv("Results.csv") # -> you do not need to save the file to a csv unless you really want to
# csv_data = pd.read_csv("Results.csv") # -> f3 is already saved in memory you do not need to read it again
# data = csv_data[['ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount']] # -> you do not need this line

f3['Logical'] = (f3['ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount']>0).astype(int)
f3.to_csv('Results2.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

## original answer

Generally you do not need to use a loop when using pandas or numpy. Take this sample dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,0,0,0,1], columns=['data'])`

You can simply use the boolean values returned (where column is greater than 0 return 1 else return 0) to create a new column.

```
df['new_col'] = (df['data'] > 0).astype(int)

   data  new_col
0     0        0
1     1        1
2     2        1
3     3        1
4     0        0
5     0        0
6     0        0
7     1        1
```

or if you want to us numpy

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['data']>0, 1, 0)

   data  new_col
0     0        0
1     1        1
2     2        1
3     3        1
4     0        0
5     0        0
6     0        0
7     1        1
```

Comment: So it will be like this? I am sorry for asking, I am just a beginner ``` import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

f1 = pd.read_csv("L1.csv")
f2 = pd.read_csv("L2.csv")
f3 = pd.merge(f1, f2, on ='CTN', how ='inner')
f3.to_csv("Results.csv")

csv_data = pd.read_csv("Results.csv")

data = csv_data[['ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount']]
data = data.to_numpy()

data['new_col'] = np.where(data['ARPU average 6 month w/t roaming and discount']>0, 1, 0)

csv_data.to_csv ('Results2.csv', index = False, header=True) ```